# Given the lat/long coordinates, how can we find out the total forest cover in that area?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth-engine

For example, if we have these set of coordinates

> "latitude": 48.858844300000001, "longitude": 2.2943506,

How dense forest is cover in that area?

Comment: What's up with your tags? Are you working with Google Maps or Google Earth Engine? These are two completely different tools.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Google Maps.
2. Put your coordinates into the search bar (remove the words "latitude" and "longitude".
3. You see the Eiffel Tower.
4. No trees grow on top of the Eiffel Tower.
5. The forest cover is zero.